# How to implement a bookmarklet for firefox 13 calling org-protocol and giving over a url/title?

Tags: firefox, javascript, bookmarklet

Since javascript in bookmarklets of firefox 13 is no longer working, is there another method to implement a button that calls org-protocol and gives over the url and the title of the actual webpage.

Comment: Huh? Bookmarklets still work in Firefox 13 if they are stored as bookmarks. Only running them from the address bar has been disabled some time ago to make it harder for worms spreading through social engineering.

Comment: So can you tell me where and how do I have to store the "javascript:location.href='org-protocol..."-command exactly.

Comment: *Show all Bookmarks (Ctrl+Shift+B)*, select folder (e.g. *Bookmarks Toolbar*), click *Organize->New bookmark...* and enter your javascript URI in the address field. You can also test your code in the web/error console.

Comment: `javascript:location.href='org-protocol://store-link://'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)` is working here as expected (exception is NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL) from console and bookmarks toolbar. See if it still happens for you if you create a new Firefox profile or run it in safe mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I was totally wrong about javascript no longer working in FF13. So I tried a little bit for my self and now I think the problem is `encodeURIComponent(location.href)`. `javascript:location.href='org-protocol://capture://p/'+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())` is running for example if I replace `encodeURIComponent(location.href)`.

Comment: `javascript:location.href='org-protocol://store-link://'+encodeURIComponent(loca‌​tion.href)` is not working for me.